# why are there no tags for Analog-to-Digital Conversion, Digital-to-Analog Conversion, and maybe Zero-order hold?

Tags: feature-request

and also abbreviated tags for ADC, DAC, and ZOH.

Comment: We've had [tag:adc] and [tag:dac] for quite a while.

Comment: it doesn't show up when i search for them.  i hit the Tags link above.  then i start typing into the Type to find tags: field and none of those tags show up.

Comment: okay, i figgered it out.  i **can't** hit "Tags" while i am in the meta SE page.  so ADC and DAC show up, but ZOH does not.

Comment: I have created [tag:zoh] per your request.

Comment: thank you @NickAlexeev.